# Direct linking to questions for tag alias causes destructive redirect

Tags: feature-request, search, new-nav, redirection

Here is a link that domonstrates this behavior:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react%20sql?mode=any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react%20sql?mode=any)

Note that:

- `react` is an alias for `reactjs`
- I included `any` as the search mode.

My browser shows that it redirects to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs%20sql

It throws away the `?mode=any` part, and it gets autofilled with `all`.

I allow users of an app to select tags and generate a link, so it is not really super easy to limit to non-alias tags.

The any and all modes are part of the question search fields when you are searching by tags:

[image]

Comment: This simply isn't a bug. Current functionality strips all query strings from a URL on a redirect, because we would have already updated user preferences based on all the valid ones that were in the URL before the redirect. You're welcome to request we *not* do this, but just saying that's unlikely to happen.

Comment: What is `mode=any`?

Comment: @Cai I assumed it's something that gets appended to the URL which helps whatever app adds it to continue functioning correctly. It's nothing we support on our sites.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The original url asks explicitly for `mode=any`. This is a valid option. After the redirect, I am given a view with `mode=all`, and no results. What user preferences are possibly involved there?

Comment: `mode=any` says "show me questions with *any* of these tags". It is a valid param, generated by your own page. It is **not** something specific to my app.

Comment: @OliviaRuth Which page adds this to the URL? I've never seen it before in all the years I've been here. If it's not working properly, it's probably because it's a forgotten feature that no one realizes even works.

Comment: @Olivia where/when/how is it generated by a Stack Exchange search? I've never seen it before

Comment: Its part of the new nav / custom search thing. Its really nice to have. See edit.

Comment: Oh this is another one of those new nav things. That entire system is... pretty broken right now. It's fate is not entirely clear. Still being discussed whether someone will be assigned to finish it or if it will just be dropped altogether. You won't see anything further happen with that until our new Product Manager gets up to speed on the project.

Comment: That's kinda crappy. Is there an equivalent feature in the old nav for showing questions marked with any of a set of tags?

Comment: @OliviaRuth The easiest thing is to mark them as favorite tags and use search for intags:mine. But you can also use OR operator between tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+or+bug

Comment: @Gerry that seems to work tolerably well across old and new nav. Thanks!

Comment: @animuson: the entire system has been working **really really well** for me, I wasn't aware of any breakage and I'd hate for it to see it die.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Me too, except for the whole forgetting that I selected 50 posts per page thing. That is rather annoying, but that aside, I have been enjoying the customization available.